# Close all tabs on Thunderbird's exit

Tags: thunderbird, tabs, thunderbird-addon

I use the actual Thunderbird 45.7.1 on Windows 7 (prof., 64-Bit).
When I open some tabs by opening new mails (I have the setting to open in new tab in my settings), all these tabs are restored when I exit Thunderbird and open it again.
Is there any way to close all tabs on Thunderbird's exit?
Or any Add-On to do this?
In Firefox this behaviour is adjustable, but not in TB.
It is the same on Windows or Mac.
The opening of mails in tabs is useful and also it can be userful to reopen all tabs, but in my scenario it is not.
Thank's

frank

EDIT: I [asked this before in a german TB Forum](https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/thread/75963-offene-tabs-beim-neustart-nicht-wieder-herstellen/?postID=416127), but no solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the main tab, click on "Close other tabs" before closing Thunderbird

Comment: I didn't ment the manual way but a setting or Add-On to do this. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

In the german forum ["Mapenzi" gave me the solution](https://www.thunderbird-mail.de/thread/75963-offene-tabs-beim-neustart-nicht-wieder-herstellen/?postID=416252#post416252), the Add-On [Thunderbird-DontRestoreTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/dontrestoretabs/) 
This seems to work :)